# Returning array value from class

Tags: php

I have a class where I've stored all the sentences inside the array.

Here is the class:

```
class Localization
{

    public function localizationString()
    {

        $strings = array(
            'customize' => 'Sentence 1',
            'detail_user' => 'Sentence 2'
        );

    }
}

$localization = new Localization();
```

I want these values to call wherever I've needed in the project.

I do that in this way:

```
echo $localization->localizationString($strings->customize);
```

I get this error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: strings in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\app\backend\pages\profile-information.php on line 49
>
> Notice: Trying to get property 'customize' of non-object in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\app\backend\pages\profile-information.php on line 49

Comment: You forgot to add the `return` statement to your method. And you are passing a parameter to the method when the method does not expect a parameter. And `$strings` is undefined outside the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem with your current solution is that when you try and use

```
$localization->localizationString($strings->customize);
```

`$strings` is only local to the `localizationString()` method (and it's an array and not an object).  So you would either have to return the `$string` array from the method or pass the key into the method and the method can then extract the value from the array.

```
public function localizationString( string $key )
{
    $strings = array(
        'customize' => 'Sentence 1',
        'detail_user' => 'Sentence 2'
    );

    return $strings[$key];
}
```

and then...

```
echo Localization::localizationString ('customize');
```

A better method is to use static class properties and methods.  Rather than having to create objects and passing arrays around all the time which is a big overhead, you define the class and data once and fetch the data from there...

```
class Localization
{
    static private $strings = array(
        'customize' => 'Sentence 1',
        'detail_user' => 'Sentence 2'
    );
    static public function localizationString( string $start ): string
    {
        return self::$strings [ $start ] ?? '';        
    }
}
```

You can then access it with...

```
echo Localization::localizationString ( 'customize' );
```

Comment: Yes, this is the right answer. Thanks. But, I'm a bit confused now. Which one is better for use? The first one or the second one? First is looking cleaner to me.

Comment: @batman  for your scenario static method answer is more appropriate. because you said that you are going to use it multiple times.So creating object every-time to just get 2-3 simple values is not a correct way to do it.

Comment: I've updated the comment, the first method still needs you to create and object, the second uses almost the same principle but without the creation part.

Answer (score -1):

You could try to access this value by changing the class to the following code:

```
class Localization
{

    public function localizationString()
    {

        $strings = array(
            'customize' => 'Sentence 1',
            'detail_user' => 'Sentence 2'
        );

        return $strings;
    }
}

$localization = new Localization();
```

and then call the function:

```
$string = $localization->localizationString();
echo $string['customize'];
echo $string['detail_user'];
```

This should work.